# Images are stable under pullback if and only if covers are

Tags: category-theory, categorical-logic

Let's say that an arrow $ f\colon X\to Y $ in a category $ \mathcal C $ *have an image* if there exists a mono $ \iota\colon \operatorname{Im} f\rightarrowtail Y $ through which $ f $ factors, such that for every other mono $ i\colon I\rightarrowtail Y $ with this property there exists a unique morphism of $ \mathcal C/Y $ from $ \iota $ to $ i $.

Moreover, call a *cover* any arrow $ \phi\colon U\to X $ such that any mono $ V\rightarrowtail X $ through which $ \phi $ factors is an isomorphism.

Johnstone in its *Elephant* claims that in a finitely complete category images are stable under pullback if and only if covers are. In other words, given $ f_1\colon X_1\to Y $ and $ f_2\colon X_2\to Y $, then $ f_2^*(\operatorname{Im}f_1)\cong \operatorname{Im}{f_2^*(f_1)} $ in $ \mathcal C/{X_2} $ if an only if the pullback of a cover is again a cover.

I have two questions:

1. I couldn't manage to prove this funny fact. Could someone help me?
2. Why we want images to be stable under pullback? Could someone provide me an example?

The really important questions is obviously pt. 1. By the way I know that I could answer pt. 2 simply by continuing reading, but having some intuition *before* trying to digest 1400 pages of math is always desirable.